# COM Interop with VB6 and C#

Tags: c#, com, vb6, com-interop

I'm writing a C# COM object that will be used by a VB 6 program. That shouldn't be much of a problem, however, the VB6 call to the COM object passes in a VB Control (in this case a TextBox). The program expects the COM object to alter the Text property of the control. Unfortunately, I have to stick to this interface as I'm dealing with someone elses legacy code.

How can I set the property for the passed in TextBox? Do I simply create an interface with a Text property and cast `input` to that interface? Is this even possible?

Please let me know if I need to clarify. Note: I intended to leave out the COM declarations in the following code.

```
// C# COM Object Interface
public interface IObj
{
    // This function must receive the argument of type object.
    void Test(object input);
}

// C# COM Object Implementation
public class Obj : IOjb
{
    // A VB6 TextBox is passed into here,
    // expecting a change to the Text property.
    public void Test(object input)
    {
        // INSERT NECESSARY CODE HERE

        input.Text = "arbitrary string";
    }
}


// VB 6
comObject.Test (txtBox)
```

Comment: How does the current COM object do it? You need to duplicate the signature of all of its methods.

Comment: The current COM object is a VB6 COM object that takes in the argument of type `object`. So this should be a duplicate of the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put code for updating the text box and any other UI specific code in to a VB6 COM object, and hand off any non-UI code to a C# class, then you will not have to deal with a VB6 UI control in C#.

Comment: Ah yea, I thought about this as a work around. It like to avoid this if possible though. Thanks though.

Comment: This feels like a much cleaner solution, why would you want to be modifying any controls from Non-UI code?

Comment: I second Ben's opinion.  Dealing with VB6 controls in a .NET solution ... you are just asking for problems.

Comment: +1. Even this is dodgy. The VB6 documentation says it's illegal to pass controls to an external component via COM. That's why it's been typed as Object in the COM interface rather than VBA.TextBox, so that the VB6 compiler lets it through. It *may* work sometimes, but I wouldn't want to rely on it myself.

Comment: @MarkJ Could you hint on where to search for the appropriate rules in the VB6 documentation? It'd be great to have an officail statement on the topic..

Comment: @mlvljr I agree it would be nice to see the official statement. I've had a quick look in the [product documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576613.aspx) but unfortunately I can't find it now :( I seem to remember it was in the "programmers guide" advice about creating ActiveX (COM) components

Comment: @MarkJ Many thanks for your help, I found it (and posted an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154895/is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-ocx-control-reference-out-from-a-visual-basic-6-activex/5167084#5167084).

Comment: @mlvljr +1 for that! I was *sure* I'd seen it somewhere, but I was beginning to doubt myself... "Component tools guide" not "programmers guide". I think this excerpt is good "Private objects are private for a reason, usually because they were not designed to be used outside your project. Passing them to a client may decrease program stability..."

Answer (score 2):

Are you using .Net 4.0?

You could try using the new dynamic language features:

```
public void Test(object input)
{
    dynamic textBox = input;
    //Assuming there is a property named Text at runtime
    textBox.Text = "arbitrary string";
}
```

This should do the equivalent of late binding in COM.

*You might also try using dynamic in your method declaration.*

Comment: Unfortunately I am not. Though if I can get my hands on VS 2010 I may give this a try.

Comment: Try the express edition of 2010 to see if it works.  Not sure if it is easier said than done if this is a huge application.

Comment: You could try this in VS 2008 or even 2005 or 2002, if you are willing to use VB.Net. Just use `Option Strict Off`. I recommend you limit `Option Strict Off` to one module. Prior to .Net 4 VB was superior to C# in this area :)